# How to change page numbering format from "1" to "Page first"?

Tags: page-numbering

In document class Article, the normal page numbering, for example is

```
1
```

I  would like to have the page number look like:

```
Page first
```

instead of:

```
1
```

How can I do it?

Comment: And `Page second` and `Page third` etc? This can get really tedious. Using something like `fmtcount` package and `fancyhdr` it is easier.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer, yes, your comment is completely right. Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask why, 'page first' doesn't sound like something I'd normally see in English. 'First page' of course is perfectly normal. Lemony Snicket rather esoterically numbered his *A Series of Unfortunate Events* books: 'book **the** first', 'book **the** second' and so on, but 'page first' really sounds like a grammar error to me, is it definitely what you're after?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer, yes, you are right. I've made a grammatical mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
.....
\usepackage{fmtcount}
.....

\begin{document}
 .....
Page\,\ordinal{page}
 .....
```

Of course, as Christian Hupfer pointed, you normally use such a code  when setting the headers/footers formatting with `fancyhdr` or `titleps`. Note that `fmtcount` is language-aware for some languages: english, french, german; italian, portuguese, spanish.

I'll give the `titleps` way:

```
\usepackage{babel}
......
\renewpagestyle{plain}
\setfoot{}{\pagename\,\ordinal{page}}{}
\pagestyle{plain}
.....
```

Comment: `\Page`?  Did I miss a command named `\Page`? (+1)

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: Bad reflex. We type so often backslashes in TeX… Actually, I thought of a multilanguage version with `babel`.

Comment: more often we we forget the backslashes ;-)

Answer (score 5):

This uses the ordinal string of the ordinal number, i.e. `1st` is `first`, etc, set in the page footer, using `fmtcount` and `fancyhdr`.

Do I recommend such a numbering style? No, it does not look nice, but I am not from the Federal Bureau of Aesthetics ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \cfoot{Page \ordinalstring{page}}
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\blindtext[50]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. The best answer! Hi.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Hello -- thanks, but 'best' is something which is primarily opinion-based